# What does "bring a human face" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The global financial crisis had brought a human face to structural wealth and income inequality in Anglo-American countries (as Thomas Piketty documented in his book Capital in the 21st Century), and to its unequal gender and race impacts.

Comment: This is the same question that you asked yesterday.  If you don't get a response,  you should edit the original rather than ask it again.

Comment: You have an answer at the original question. If that doesn't help, it's OK to ask another question rather than edit the original (which could invalidate the answer there); **but** your second question (this one) **must** explain why you have asked it and why it is not simply answered by the previous question. That is, the second question must be quite significantly different from the first.